# Algorithm to read and write command line string

Tags: command-line, terminal, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to write a program that can read a command string and validate it (get the name of the command and it's arguments), change those arguments and then rewrite the command string dynamically.

I'm looking for an Algorithm or regEx that can parse a command string. I'm familiar with DOS 6.2 and batch files but I know very little about Mac like terminal, unix, shell, etc which is what I'm using. I'm not sure if the arguments is a different syntax from one command to the next.

More info:
Things I have to do is validate that a command line is formatted correctly, for example, where paths to files have quotes around them or escape spaces if they are there. I would like it to be generic so that it can work with any command.

I'm using a Mac so I can test in Terminal.

Comment: I'm very unclear on what you're asking here... can you provide an example? Are you suggesting that you want to write a program that, when called from the command line, does input validation and then calls other installed programs? If so, in what language are you planning on doing your development?

Comment: If you read the string like ls command and -l options using command line argument and validate that its command or not?

Comment: I suspect you'll find you have a bit of learning to do before you're able to rephrase this question in a way where we'll really be able to help. Things to keep in mind: each program can parse its command line arguments however it wants, and there really aren't standards. And multiple programs can interact on the command line, in a way defined by the current shell. Things to think about: All of `program "/path/to file"`, `program /path/to\ file`, and `program /path/to file` are legal. Also: how do you validate `echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5" | perl -lne 'print if (1x$_) !~ /^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$/'`?

Comment: @addaon - I see your point. I didn't know that each program can parse it's command line however it wants. So does that mean when I run a command like, "program -e | blah blah blah 123", "program" is getting a string containing everything after the phrase "program "?

Comment: It's up to the shell, which is the (interactive, in this case) program that reads the input and passes it on to other programs (after doing its own validation). In the example you give, no, it's rather more complex than that. Most shells will pass `program` the `-e` option, then past `blah` the (separate) options `blah`, `blah`, and `123`, and also configure the I/O of the programs such that the standard output of `program` is connected to the standard input of `blah` (the meaning of the pipe character in common shells).

Answer (score -1):

```
        #include<stdio.h>

             main(int argc,char *argv[])

                {
            if(execlp(argv[1], argv[1], argv[2], "/usr/", (char *) 0)==-1)

               printf("This is not valid command\n");

              exit(0);

                }
```

Run the program :

```
         ./a.out ls -lhrt
```

This program handled more than one options.

which  directory you want change it instead of the "/usr" directory

You run the program dynamically and change the command and options .

Comment: sorry . I know only the this concept.you read the exec system call functions and you will get more information about it.

Comment: So I'm not quite familiar with that language. Does the program above take a command like, "ls" and parse out it's arguments into an array or something? In this case, it would have an array where the first and item is "-l"? If you added more arguments like, "-l -define=Config::value,true" it would have two items in the array where the first would be "-l" and the second would be, "-define=Config::value,true"?

Comment: This program isn't really doing any parsing at all... instead, it's just calling the given program with the first argument provided, under the further constraint that the program live in the `/usr` directory.